# Comparison of same property in different objects-JSON schema

Tags: python, json, schema

Please see below json schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstname": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "lastname": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "post_sql": {

      "type": "object",
      "properties": {

        "datasets": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {

            "type": "object",
            "properties": {

              "firstname": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "lastname": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "access": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                  "type": "string"
                }

              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to compare firstname and lastname of first object which is at top with firstname and lastname which is inside post_sql->datasets if they are same then all accesses to that user ["insert","update","delete"] else only["select"] access for different user.

sample data:

```
{
  "registration": {
    "firstname": "john",
    "lastname": "dharman",
          
    "post_sql": {
      
      "datasets": [
        {
          "firstname": "john",
          "lastname": "dharman",
          "access": [
            "select","insert","update","delete"
          ]
        },
        {
          "firstname": "jenny",
          "lastname": "shein",
          "access": [
            "select","insert","update","delete"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }

  }
}
```

in above example

```
"firstname": "john",
        "lastname": "dharman"
```

are same in first object and in post_sql->datasets:

```
"post_sql": {

 

 
  "datasets": [
    {
      "firstname": "john",
      "lastname": "dharman",
      "access": [
        "select","insert","update","delete"
      ]
    },
```

so john should get all accesses but if firstname and last name are not same(like jenny in above data) then we need to give only ["select"] like in above example second object have one more dataset with:

```
{
              "firstname": "jenny",
              "lastname": "shein",
              "access": [
                "select","insert","update","delete"
              ]
            }
```

so I want such if-else in my json schema where it will check firstname and lastname with second object and based on that if both are same then all access array should be given to that user

```
[
                    "select","insert","update","delete"
                  ]
```

else only

```
["select"]
```

I tried to put if else in datasets but some how it did not work please help in this. We just need if->else-> then statements but its just this json schema contains a bit nested objects in one schema.

Comment: Thanks for providing your code, and what you tried. Can you update your question with specifics of what happened when you ran your code? Additionally, it may help people answer your question if you can simplify it a bit - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for some guidance on how to do that.

Comment: @MatthewCox I have simplified the code as well as question.  Its combination of nested objects with different properties.  I want above comparison of same properties which are there for tow different objects!! a bit complex !